# Youtube Data API v3 requests sent twice

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm creating youtube subscribers counter but when I send one request, Google Developers Console says I sent two requests and my quota limit reaches limit twice faster.

I've tried to make the request in Google Chrome and it also makes two requests instead of one.

```js
function getSubsCount() {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=' + id + '&key=' + key;
    $.getJSON(url, data => {
        div.html(data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
    })
}

function getSubsCount() {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=' + id + '&key=' + key;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        div.innerHTML = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
    }
}
```

I am making two requests (2 channels) per 12s, so that must be 0.166req/s, but it is 0.333req/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Chrome sends a GET request, it sends an additional request to /favicon.ico, Google created a bad browser for Google APIs

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified the exact numbers Google is displaying.

Anyway, I guess that you assume that each of your API requests costs you one quota unit.

In fact, each and every query to the API's Channel endpoint for `list` method and `part=statistics` has a cost of [3 quota units](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).